# How to adapt line height according to current font size in Quill?

Tags: css, editor, quill

I've been asked to change the default font size to 54px in Quill, so I have added this to my style sheet :

```
.ql-editor {
  font-size: 54px;
}
```

I also added a combo to select font size.

The problem is occurring when I mix different font sizes on different lines.
The line height used is, I suppose, 54px so it give me this result:

[image: Quill mixing fonts example]

Is there a way to have each line using the line height relative to the selected font?

Comment: nothing happens  when you try ?  `.ql-editor {line-height: normal ;}` ?

Comment: I have just tried, nothing happens.

Comment: is it possible for you to make a demo where it doesnt work ? using code pen or js fiddle combined with your libraries. ? the source will help others to find the issue.